# Error compiling clojurescript, on my first try

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, clojurescript, leiningen

Details :

1. Windows 10 machine (64-Bit)
2. Java version - 14 (Its on my %PATH%)
3. Clojure script version - 1.10.597
4. Leiningen version - 2.9.3 (Its on my %PATH%)
5. Java runs on my computer !!
6. My internet connection is stable

My project dir : 
C:\Users[username]\Desktop\TicTacToe\tictac\src\tictac

Im new to Clore/Clojurescripts/Lisp and im currently following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIiOgTwjbes tutorial.

Commands I have executed on my cmd (on dir : C:\Users[username]\Desktop\TicTacToe) :

```
lein new figwheel tictac

cd tictac

lein figwheel
```

and every time i run the last command (3rd), I get a compiler error... and its not the same error when I run the command multiple times.

The usual error that i get is :

(Im running this command for the first time (never compiled a clojure file before), also its retrieving a lot of items (and again its different each time i run it))

```
Could not find artifact figwheel-sidecar:figwheel-sidecar:jar:0.5.19 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not transfer artifact figwheel-sidecar:figwheel-sidecar:jar:0.5.19 from/to clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/): Failed to transfer file: https://repo.clojars.org/figwheel-sidecar/figwheel-sidecar/0.5.19/figwheel-sidecar-0.5.19.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Backend unavailable, connection timeout.
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

(NOTE : Im not behind a proxy)

Comment: I tried many different hello word programs, none of them work(with and without Leiningen)

Comment: Still could be a network issue: `Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Backend unavailable, connection timeout`

Comment: Go to `figwheel.org` and follow the Tutorial using Deps/CLI, not Leiningen.  Much better experience.

Comment: "Could not find artifact..." looks like a Leiningen message. So the good news is, you're not using Figwheel yet and you'll have a grand time after you clear up the network or network-access problem. Two ideas: (1) Firewall software blocking certain programs from the internet? (2) Old `.m2/settings.xml` or `.lein/profiles.clj` with leftover settings from earlier experiments?

Comment: Hi, in my experience many templates are outdated… I've found that the easiest way to set up a Clojurescript Project and actually understand the build process is to use shadow-cljs…